# Plotly 3D camera up direction doesn't change

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

This is possibly a bug in plotly. I have set the camera "up" direction to be the y-axis, like so

```
layout = {
    'scene': {
        'camera': {
            'up': {'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 0}
        }
    }
}
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

but the plot produced still has the default z-axis as the "up" direction. Have I done something wrong, or is this indeed a bug? In none of the documentation do they actually show an example of changing the "up" direction, so has anyone actually been able to do it?

#### Update

I have [opened an issue on plotly.py's GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/815).

Comment: I came across the same problem, when I tried to invert the graph by setting z to -1.